# How to flush printer queue via command line on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, printer, printing, network-printer

How can I flush the printer queue with cmd.exe on Windows 7?

Comment: Why do I get negative votes, idiots at work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Type the following commands into an elevated command prompt:

```
net stop spooler

del %systemroot%\system32\spool\printers\*.shd

del %systemroot%\system32\spool\printers\*.spl

net start spooler
```

Or make a batch file to run those commands.

[Source](http://sumtips.com/2011/04/fix-stuck-print-jobs-in-windows.html)

[Then there is the hidden VBScript Utilities](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/discover-the-power-of-windows-7-hidden-vbscript-print-utilities/5645)